# Javascript: change web page opacity on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to dim a web page when a specific image is clicked on, using JavaScript. I had a look around and managed to get this far:

I have to create the image div on the fly, as indicated below. To change the screen opacity I created a ‘screen’ div inside the html document and set its opacity to 0. It works.  The aim is to be able to add an attribute to the image div so that when it is clicked, the opacity of the screen div is changed to, say, 0.5. This solution below works, but in the sense that the screen div immediately changes opacity when I open it, rather than when the image is clicked. Also, I need to somehow figure out how to unset the opacity change once the image is clicked a second time. I guess I need a boolean + if-statement for this but can’t figure out how it might work in this situation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = “images/myImage.jpg”;
    img.onclick = dimmerSwitch();   
    document.body.appendChild(img);

function dimmerSwitch (){   
    var elem = document.getElementById("dimmer").style["opacity"] = "0.55";
}
```

Comment: Change the 3rd line to `img.onclick = dimmerSwitch;`. Your code immediately calls `dimmerSwitch` (with the `()`), when you need to set the `onclick` with the reference to the function so that it can be called at the right time (on click)

Comment: Also, it looks like you're using special quotes - `“ ”`. You should probably change those to normal quotes - `" "`

Comment: Did the answer solve the issue..?

Comment: I had some issues with this one. I could not get the code to work for this problem. However, I reused parts of the solution in a different scenario and got results.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need `var elem` variable in `dimmerSwitch`

```
function dimmerSwitch (){   
    document.getElementById("dimmer").style.opacity = "0.55";
}
```

would do the trick!

Also to toggle, the neater method would be to define css classes and toggle between them in your dimmerSwitch function, like

```
.dimmed{
  opacity: 0.55;
}
```

Here's a neat tutorial which explains how you could do that: http://toddmotto.com/stop-toggling-classes-with-js-use-behaviour-driven-dom-manipulation-with-data-states/

Comment: Using `document.getElementById("")` everywhere requires accessing the DOM each time. Keeping a reference to the accessed element is a good practice when it needs to be access repeatedly

Comment: If you notice, I am just using it just once in my function :) So, doesn't really matter.

Comment: Can you come up with a way of doing the switch using it just once?

Comment: Yes, that's what I just described, if you read the tutorial link I posted.

Comment: and for your information, down vote is to indicating that an answer might have something wrong with it or when it can be improved. and it'd be nice to leave a comment when you down vote something.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I did *not* down-vote your answer, if you are assuming that.

Comment: And if you actually read the tutorial you shared, you can see that the author is keeping reference to elements.

Comment: My comment was about `var elem = document.getElementById("dimmer").style["opacity"] = "0.55";` statement used in the code in the question.

Comment: That is not an answer for what the OP wants to do... you can leave that as a comment (Comments are there for a reason) and the rest of your answer doesn't answer the question other than sharing a link...